# How to update list items?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have been trying to programmatically update list items on a sharepoint website using c#.
I was able to successfully do the `WebServerReference` . However I do not understand what the following items are:

`ListId, viewId , FieldName ID` etc

In the following piece of code that I took from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms440289%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
I am supposed to substitute these `ListId, viewId , FieldName ID` values for my values. I have noidea where I can get those value. I have been scrutinizing my sharepoint website , but was not able to find these values anywhere.

```
/*Get Name attribute values (GUIDs) for list and view. */
System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = listService.GetListAndView("MyList", "");
string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
string strViewID = ndListView.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value;

/*Create an XmlDocument object and construct a Batch element and its
attributes. Note that an empty ViewName parameter causes the method to use the default view. */
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement batchElement = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
batchElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
batchElement.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
batchElement.SetAttribute("ViewName", strViewID);

/*Specify methods for the batch post using CAML. To update or delete, 
specify the ID of the item, and to update or add, specify 
the value to place in the specified column.*/
batchElement.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
   "<Field Name='ID'>6</Field>" +
   "<Field Name='Title'>Modified sixth item</Field></Method>" +
   "<Method ID='2' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID'>7</Field>" +
   "<Field Name='Title'>Modified seventh item</Field></Method>" +
   "<Method ID='3' Cmd='Delete'><Field Name='ID'>5</Field>" +
   "</Method><Method ID='4' Cmd='New'>" +
   "<Field Name='Title'>Added item</Field></Method>";
```

Comment: You can use the display name of the list as the list ID if you don't want to use the GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try browsing to the list settings page to get the list ID from the URL, the modify view page to get the view ID from the URL, and the list settings page then click on a field to get the field name from the URL. Or you could try something like SharePoint Manager on Codeplex to find this information easily.